# How to add @ManagedAttribute and @ManagedOperation to an MBean that extends another class

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, jmx

I have created an `MBean` that extends a class and implements interfaces.

I am trying to add some new `@ManagedAttribute` and `@ManagedOperation` but they are not shown in jconsole.

I also see that the descriptions of the other attributes and operations are not shown correctly. The descriptions are set to default, although I set them in my class.

Is there any way to add new `@ManagedAttribute` and `@ManagedOperation` to my `MBean`?

And can I set the descriptions?

 I create two instances of the `MBean` class with `@MBean` annotation.

 Is the problem that the `MBean` created is of type `StandardBean` and not `DynamicBean`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare manage Attributes and operation on your interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mark the MBean with @ManagedResource to register it with the JMX Server.
And also mark it as a @Component.